# Unable to center the active slider with carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [Lemmon Juice slider](http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php) for my website to get carousel that supports slided elements with variable widths. I was able to implement the slider with the following code stated in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emil_j/uja1c7am/1/).

I need to get the active slider to be centered with next and previous sliders stacked to the right and left of the active slider. With some reference I was able to center the active slider with some code changes in the JS file. But unfortunately the auto play function and the Next slider button stopped working with the changes which is stated in the [JSFiddle-2](https://jsfiddle.net/emil_j/9kvym4zj/1/).

```
function slideTo( e, $slider, x, i, t ){

    $slider.items.filter( 'li:eq(' + i + ')' ).addClass( 'active' ).siblings( '.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );


    // This function is added to center the carousel.
    if( $slider.options.center ) {
        var currentElement = $( $slider.items[ i ] );
        $slider.options.offset = Math.floor( ( $( window ).width() - currentElement.width() ) / 2 );
        console.log( 'set offset to ', $slider.options.offset );
    }

    if ( typeof t == 'undefined' ){
        t = 'fast';
    }
    if ( t ){

        //$slider.animate({ 'scrollLeft' : x }, t, function(){   - changed to below
        $slider.animate({ 'scrollLeft' : x  - $slider.options.offset }, t, function(){ 
            checkInfinite( $slider );
        });
    } else {
        var time = 0;
        // $slider.scrollLeft( x ); changed to below
        $slider.scrollLeft( x - $slider.options.offset );
        checkInfinite( $slider );
    }

    //if ( typeof $slider.options.slide == 'function' ) $slider.options.slide( e, i, time );

}
function checkInfinite( $slider ){

    var $active = $slider.items.filter( '.active' );
    if ( $active.hasClass( '-before' ) ){

        var i = $active.prevAll().size();
        $active.removeClass( 'active' );
        $active = $slider.items.filter( ':not(.-before):eq(' + i + ')' ).addClass( 'active' );
        // $slider.scrollLeft( $slider.scrollLeft() + $active.position().left); changed to below
        $slider.scrollLeft( $slider.scrollLeft() + $active.position().left - $slider.options.offset );
    } else if ( $active.hasClass( '-after' ) ){

        var i = $active.prevAll( '.-after' ).size();
        $active.removeClass( 'active' );
        $active = $slider.items.filter( ':not(.-before):eq(' + i + ')' ).addClass( 'active' );
        //$slider.scrollLeft( $slider.scrollLeft() + $active.position().left ); changed to below
        $slider.scrollLeft( $slider.scrollLeft() + $active.position().left - $slider.options.offset );

    }

}
```

And

```
$.fn.lemmonSlider.defaults = {

    'items'       : '> *',
    'loop'        : true,
    'slideToLast' : false,
    'slider'      : '> *:first',
    // since 0.2
    'infinite'    : true,
    // additional codes
    'center':      true,
    'offset':      0

}
```

Please help me to get this rectified. Anyone who could help to sort this out would be much appreciated. 
Thanks a lot in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked up your fiddele:
What I observed is that it is not able to load the plugin and this causes your auto scroll functionality and the next slide button stop working.

oRefer yuur console in jsfiddle to see the errors and rectify them out.

Just make sure that the plugin is loaded correctly before you call the functions of the slider.

I would recommend you to search for owlcarousel and use it in your project as it provides much flexibility and easy handling..

Thanks

Comment: Hi kshitij, Thanks for you reply. If the plugin is not loaded, then how could it work for the first JSFiddle.. The function that I created is making some conflicts with the nextSlide button. If the nextSlide button works, autoplay function will also work. Since autoplay function is just triggering the nextSlide button.

Comment: I tried the Owlcarousel plugin. It is a great plugin. Since I need the active slider to be centered, this plugin doesn't provide the option to do that. And it won't support images with varying widths.  Thanks for the suggestion.